# Is TORCoin officially endorsed by the Tor Project?

Tags: torproject.org

Is the TORCoin cryptocurrency officially endorsed by the Tor Project ?

Answer (score 1):

No.

See [this tweet](https://twitter.com/torproject/status/855882107234770944).

> Warning: @TheTorCoin is using our name & logo without permission or approval. Their service is not endorsed by or affiliated with Tor.